# What is the difference between std::move and std::forward?

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding, stdmove

I saw this here:
[Move Constructor calling base-class Move Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390888/move-constructor-calling-base-class-move-constructor)

Could someone explain:

1. the difference between [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) and [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward), preferably with some code examples?
2. How to think about it easily, and when to use which

Comment: See also these two related questions: [Should I use std::move or std::forward in move ctors/assignment operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8860233/500104) and [How does std::forward work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8526598/500104) (aswell as the duplicated question).

Comment: "How to think about it easily, and when to use which" You use `move` when you want to *move* a value, and `forward` when you want to use perfect forwarding. This isn't rocket science here ;)

Comment: move() perform unconditional cast where as forward() perform cast based on the parameter that has passed.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

`std::move` takes an object and allows you to treat it as a temporary (an rvalue). Although it isn't a semantic requirement, typically a function accepting a reference to an rvalue will invalidate it. When you see `std::move`, it indicates that the value of the object should not be used afterwards, but you can still assign a new value and continue using it.

`std::forward` has a single use case: to cast a templated function parameter (inside the function) to the value category (lvalue or rvalue) the caller used to pass it. This allows rvalue arguments to be passed on as rvalues, and lvalues to be passed on as lvalues, a scheme called "perfect forwarding."

To [illustrate](http://ideone.com/z5li7):

```
void overloaded( int const &arg ) { std::cout << "by lvalue\n"; }
void overloaded( int && arg ) { std::cout << "by rvalue\n"; }

template< typename t >
/* "t &&" with "t" being template param is special, and  adjusts "t" to be
   (for example) "int &" or non-ref "int" so std::forward knows what to do. */
void forwarding( t && arg ) {
    std::cout << "via std::forward: ";
    overloaded( std::forward< t >( arg ) );
    std::cout << "via std::move: ";
    overloaded( std::move( arg ) ); // conceptually this would invalidate arg
    std::cout << "by simple passing: ";
    overloaded( arg );
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "initial caller passes rvalue:\n";
    forwarding( 5 );
    std::cout << "initial caller passes lvalue:\n";
    int x = 5;
    forwarding( x );
}
```

As Howard mentions, there are also similarities as both these functions simply cast to reference type. But outside these specific use cases (which cover 99.9% of the usefulness of rvalue reference casts), you should use `static_cast` directly and write a good explanation of what you're doing.

Comment: I'm not sure it's accurate that `std::forward`'s _only_ use case is perfect forwarding of function arguments. I've run into situations where I want to perfectly forward other things, like object members.

Comment: @GeoffRomer Members of a parameter? Do you have an example?

Comment: I posted an example as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616958/stdforward-without-perfect-forwarding

Comment: Hmm, so if I understand this correctly, it means that I can write a single function forward() where forward(5) operates on 5 as if I passed it by value where forward(x) operates on x as if I passed it by reference without having to explicitly write an overload.

Comment: @iheanyi Yep, that's the idea! But it has to be a template, not just an ordinary function.

Comment: Thanks. I did some more reading and I think I understand the use with templates. Your answer did a lot to help me wrap my head around the concept :)

Comment: If std::forward passes on the rvalue to overloaded, I could imagine overloaded to invalidate the object because it assumes the object was moved. How is std::forward avoiding this situation?

Comment: @MaximilianMordig You are correct. Only pass an object to `std::forward` if it is ready to be invalidated in the rvalue case.

Comment: A slightly tangential, noob question: since fowarding takes t&&, it means it accepts rvalues for that parameter.  Why is forwarding(x) valid then, since it's passing an lvalue?

Comment: @Pratik when you declaring an expression as `T&& expression;`, it could be either rvalue or lvalue. If `expression` has a name, it is lvalue; Otherwise, it is rvalue. So if you have `Class C{ C(const C&){} C(C&&){} }; void Func( C&& arg ){ C a(arg); }`, The copy constructor `C(const C&)` will be called. Due to the argument `arg` is lvalue.

Comment: Why does `std::forward` require you to explicitly specify the template parameter instead of deducing it like `std::move` does?

Answer (score 69):

Both `std::forward` and `std::move` are nothing but casts.

```
X x;
std::move(x);
```

The above casts the lvalue expression `x` of type X to an rvalue expression of type X (an xvalue to be exact).  `move` can also accept an rvalue:

```
std::move(make_X());
```

and in this case it is an identity function:  takes an rvalue of type X and returns an rvalue of type X.

With `std::forward` you can select the destination to some extent:

```
X x;
std::forward<Y>(x);
```

Casts the lvalue expression `x` of type X to an expression of type Y.  There are constraints on what Y can be.

Y can be an accessible Base of X, or a reference to a Base of X.  Y can be X, or a reference to X.  One can not cast away cv-qualifiers with `forward`, but one can add cv-qualifiers.  Y can not be a type that is merely convertible  from X, except via an accessible Base conversion.

If Y is an lvalue reference, the result will be an lvalue expression.  If Y is not an lvalue reference, the result will be an rvalue (xvalue to be precise) expression.

`forward` can take an rvalue argument only if Y is not an lvalue reference.  That is, you can not cast an rvalue to lvalue.  This is for safety reasons as doing so commonly leads to dangling references.  But casting an rvalue to rvalue is ok and allowed.

If you attempt to specify Y to something that is not allowed, the error will be caught at compile time, not run time.

Comment: If I perfectly forward an object to a function using `std::forward`, then after that function is executed, can I use that object? I am aware that, in case of `std::move`, it's an undefined behavior.

Comment: Regarding `move`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7028318/576911  For `forward`, if you pass in an lvalue, your API should react as if it receives an lvalue.  Normally this means the value will be unmodified.  But if it is a non-const lvalue, your API may have modified it.  If you pass in an rvalue, this normally means that your API may have moved from it, and thus https://stackoverflow.com/a/7028318/576911 would apply.

Answer (score 25):

I think comparing two example implementations can provide a lot of insight on what they are for and how they differ.

Let's start with `std::move`.

### `std::move`

Long story short: `std::move` is for turning *anything* into an rvalue(¹), for the purpose of making it look like a temporary (even if it isn't: `std::move(non_temporary)`), so that its resources can be stolen from it, i.e. *moved* from it (provided this is not prevented by a `const` attribute; yes, rvalues can be `const`, in which case you can't steal resources from them).

`std::move(x)` says *Hi guys, be aware that who I'm giving this `x` to can use and break it apart as he likes*, so you typically use it on rvalue references parameters, because you're sure they are bound to temporaries.

This is a C++14 implementation of `std::move` very similar to what Scott Meyers shows in [Effective Modern C++](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-modern-c/9781491908419/) (in the book the return type `std::remove_reference_t<T>&&` is changed to `decltype(auto)`, which deduces it from the `return` statement)

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::remove_reference_t<T>&& move(T&& t) {
    return static_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>&&>(t);
}
```

From this we can observe the following about `std::move`:

- it is a **template function**, so it works on any type `T`;
- it takes its sole parameter via **universal (or forwarding) reference `T&&`**, so it can operate on both lvalues and rvalues; `T` will correspondingly be deduced as an lvalue reference or as a non-reference type;
- **template type deduction *is* in place**, so you don't have to specify the template argument via `<…>`, and, in practice, you should never specify it;
- this also means that `std::move` is nothing more than a `static_cast` with the template argument automatically determined based on the non-template argument, whose type is deduced;
- it **returns an rvalue** without making any copy, by using an rvalue reference type (instead of a non-reference type) for the return type; it does so by stripping any reference-ness from `T`, via `std::remove_reference_t`, and then adding `&&`.

### Trivia

Do you know that, beside the [`std::move` from `<utility>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) that we are talking about, there's another one? Yeah, it's [`std::move` from `<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move), which does a half-related thing: it's a version of [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) which, instead of copying values from one container to another, it *moves* them, using `std::move` from `<utility>`; so it is a `std::move` which uses the other `std::move`!

### `std::forward`

Long story short: `std::forward` is for forwarding an argument from inside a function to another function while telling the latter function whether the former was called with a temporary.

`std::forward<X>(x)` says one of two things:

- (if `x` is bound to an rvalue, i.e. a temporary) *Hi Mr Function, I've received this parcel from another function who doesn't need it after you work with it, so please feel free to do whatever you like with it*;
- (if `x` is bound to an lvalue, i.e. a non-temporary) *Hi Mr Function, I've received this parcel from another function who does need it after you work with it, so please don't break it*.

So you typically use it on forwarding/universal references, because they can bind to both temporaries and non temporaries.

In other words, `std::forward` is for being able to turn this code

```cpp
template<typename T>
void wrapper(T&& /* univ. ref.: it binds to lvalues as well as rvalues (temporaries)*/ t) {
    // here `t` is an lvalue, so it doesn't know whether it is bound to a temporary;
    // `T` encodes this missing info, but sadly we're not making `some_func` aware of it,
    // therefore `some_func` will not be able to steal resources from `t` if `t`
    // is bound to a temporary, because it has to leave lvalues intact
    some_func(t);
}
```

into this

```cpp
template<typename T>
void wrapper(T&& /* univ. ref.: it binds to lvalues as well as rvalues (temporaries)*/ t) {
    // here `t` is an lvalue, so it doesn't know whether it is bound to a temporary;
    // `T` encodes this missing info, and we do use it:
    // `t` bound to lvalue => `T` is lvalue ref => `std::forward` forwards `t` as lvalue
    // `t` bound to rvalue => `T` is non-ref    => `std::forward` turns `t` into rvalue
    some_func(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

This is the C++14 implementation of `std::forward` from the same book:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T&& forward(std::remove_reference_t<T>& t) {
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

From this we can observe the following about `std::forward`:

- it is a **template function**, so it works on any type `T`;
- it takes its sole parameter via lvalue reference to a reference-less `T`; note that, because of *Reference collapsing* (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)), `std::remove_reference_t<T>&` resolves exactly to the same thing as `T&` would resolve to; however...
- ... the reason why `std::remove_reference_t<T>&` is used instead of `T&` is ***exactly*** to put `T` in a *non-deduced context* (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)), thus ***disabling* template type deduction**, so that you are *forced* to specify the template argument via `<…>`
- this also means that `std::forward` is nothing more than a `static_cast` with the template argument automatically determined (via reference collapsing) based on the template argument that you must pass to `std::forward`;
- it **returns an rvalue or an lvalue** without making any copy, by using an rvalue reference or lvalue reference type (instead of a non-reference type) for the return type; it does so by relying on reference collapsing applied to `T&&`, where `T` is the one that you passed as template argument to `std::forward`: if that `T` is a non-reference, then `T&&` is an rvalue reference, whereas if `T` is an lvalue reference, then `T&&` is an lvalue reference too;
- some people writes `static_cast<T&&>` instead of `std::forward<T>`, because that's what it is, and they save an instatiation, [at the expense of less clear code and possibility to not catch bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257824/why-use-stdforwardt-instead-of-static-castt).

---

¹ Scott Meyers in *Effective Modern C++* says precisely the following:

> `std::move` unconditionally casts its argument to an rvalue

Comment: _"Long story short: std::move is for turning anything into an rvalue"_. That is not 100% correct. It cannot turn _anything_ into an rvalue (which can be moved, or stolen from). If the argument has constness in it, then `std::move` wont change that fact, and then you wont be able to move the result.

Comment: @Nawaz, from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) it appears to me that `std::move(whatever)` is a xvalue, hence an rvalue. Whether that rvalue is `const` or not is another story. And it has its consequences as you suggest (can't be moved from). But I think my statement is correct nonetheless.

Comment: @Nawaz, `const` is part of the _type_, which is a property (of an expression) independent from the _value category_ property (see first paragraph [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)). Therefore, I think my statement is 100% correct, as I didn't write _turn anything into a **modifiable** rvalue_.

Comment: @Nawaz, here's a citation.

Comment: If I take your statement completely, then it's wrong. As you said (see the emphasis): _"Long story short: std::move is for turning anything into an rvalue(¹), for the purpose of making it look like a temporary (even if it isn't: std::move(non_temporary)), **so that it's resources can be stolen from it (i.e. moved from it)**."_ So it seems you're under the impression that `std::move()` will make the argument _steal-able_ no matter what

Comment: That's not what you commented initially. However, I'll add a couple of words.

Comment: That is my comment. See it carefully. I didn't quote it completely, as it's verbose and comment has limit on number of characters. I simply rephrased it in the braces "(which can be moved, or stolen from)" which you probably ignored.

Comment: Good, added some words now.

Comment: Looks great now! Thanks for the edit. Upvoted. :-)

Comment: Thank you for prompting me to improve it. And yes, I didn't notice that piece in parenthesis of your first comment.

Comment: Great! move casts the parameter to an rvalue; forward forwards the parameter as it is (unchanged) received either it’s an lvalue or an rvalue, so that the last function that receives the forwarded value can be aware of what to or not to do with the received value.

Answer (score 22):

`std::forward` is used to *forward* a parameter exactly the way it was passed to a function. Just like shown here:

[When to use std::forward to forward arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257144/when-to-use-stdforward-to-forward-arguments)

Using `std::move` offers an object as an rvalue, to possibly match a move constructor or a function accepting rvalues. It does that for `std::move(x)` even if `x` is not an rvalue by itself.