# User-defined move constructor for member of lvalue reference type

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I'm playing around with move semantics on a compiler, which has rvalue references but does not support defaulted move constructors. I would like to generate something like the wrapper class below, which works even if the template parameter is an lvalue reference. However, this straightforward approach does not compile because it tries to initialize an int& from an int.

```
#define USER_DEFINED   0

template <typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
    Wrapper(T t)
        : m_t(t)
    {
    }

    Wrapper(const Wrapper&) = delete;
    Wrapper& operator=(const Wrapper&) = delete;

#if USER_DEFINED
    Wrapper(Wrapper&& w)
        : m_t(std::move(w.m_t))
    {
    }
#else
    Wrapper(Wrapper&&) = default;
#endif

private:
    T m_t;
};

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    Wrapper<int&> w1 = Wrapper<int&>(i);
    Wrapper<std::string> w2 = Wrapper<std::string>("text");
}
```

The obvious solution would be to have two move constructors, one for lvalue references and one for all other types. Something like this for example:

```
template <typename U = T>
Wrapper(typename std::enable_if<!std::is_lvalue_reference<U>::value, Wrapper>::type&& w)
    : m_t(std::move(w.m_t))
{
}

template <typename U = T>
Wrapper(typename std::enable_if<std::is_lvalue_reference<U>::value, Wrapper>::type&& w)
    : m_t(w.m_t)
{
}
```

So is this the way to go? Maybe the expression inside the `enable_if<>` should be more generic? Or can I use something different from std::move() and have one single constructor for all types?

Comment: I'm hesitating to post this as an answer because I'm not sure it will do the right thing but what about replacing `std::move` with `std::forward`?

Comment: @5gon12eder:  Go for it.  You are on the right track.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thank you.  I gave it a try and it seems to work but I would be glad for some feedback if you have the time because I don't fully understand why it actually works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, here is a solution that I think will work as you want it but I must admit that I don't fully understand how it does so.

The most important change I've made was to replace `std::move` with [`std::forward<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) in the move constructor.  I have also added a move assignment operator but here is the thing I don't understand: Unless everywhere else, it needs `std::move` instead of `std::forward`!  Finally, I have also added a `std::forward` to your constructor that accepts a `T` so it doesn't make *two* copies of its argument.  It is actually required that we accept the `T` by value and use `std::forward` here.  Overloading for `const T&` and `T&&` would fail if `T` is a reference because then `T&&` would also [*collapse*](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) to an lvalue reference and the overload become ambiguous.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class Wrapper
{

public:

  Wrapper(T t) : m_t {std::forward<T>(t)}
  {
  }

  Wrapper(Wrapper&& w) : m_t {std::forward<T>(w.m_t)}
  {
  }

  Wrapper(const Wrapper&) = delete;

  Wrapper&
  operator=(Wrapper&& w)
  {
    if (this != &w)
      this->m_t = std::move(w.m_t);
    return *this;
  }

  Wrapper&
  operator=(const Wrapper&) = delete;

private:

  T m_t;
};
```

Now, let's take it for a test drive with an instrumented type that allows us see what is going on.

```
struct A
{
  A ()
  {
    std::cerr << "A was default-constructed" << std::endl;
  }

  A (const A&)
  {
    std::cerr << "A was copy-constructed" << std::endl;
  }

  A (A&&)
  {
    std::cerr << "A was move-constructed" << std::endl;
  }

  A&
  operator=(const A&)
  {
    std::cerr << "A was copy-assigned" << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }

  A&
  operator=(A&&)
  {
    std::cerr << "A was move-assigned" << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }

  ~A ()
  {
    std::cerr << "A was destroyed" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  A a {};
  Wrapper<A> val1 {a};
  Wrapper<A> val2 {std::move(val1)};
  val1 = std::move(val2);
  Wrapper<A&> ref1 {a};
  Wrapper<A&> ref2 {std::move(ref1)};
  ref1 = std::move(ref2);
}
```

Compiled with GCC 4.9.1 (Where the whole exercise is actually rather pointless because it supports all kinds of moves already out of the box.) and all optimizations turned off, the output is as follows (comments added).

```lisp
A was default-constructed  ; automatic variable a in main
A was copy-constructed     ; copied as Wrapper<A>'s constructor argument
A was move-constructed     ; forwarded in Wrapper<A>'s initializer
A was destroyed            ; the moved-away from copy as the constructor returns
A was move-constructed     ; forwarded in Wrapper<A>'s move-constructor
A was move-assigned        ; move-assignment operator in Wrapper<A>
A was move-assigned        ; not sure about this one... (apparently caused by the Wrapper<A&> move-assignment)
A was destroyed            ; the sub-object of val2
A was destroyed            ; the sub-object of val1
A was destroyed            ; the automatic variable a in main
```

Comment: Anyone who says that C++ has not become an unintelligible mess is crazy.

Comment: How is assignment supposed to work for a class with a reference member?

Comment: Your first constructor used `std::forward` without using a universal reference, and that was not quite correct (check out Scott Meyers' article on universal references, or his new *Effective Modern C++*). Changing it to something like `template <typename U> Wrapper(U&& t) : m_t{std::forward<U>(t)} ...` will reduce one move-construction and one destruction.

Comment: @5gon12eder Thanks for the help. However, I also do not understand how std::move and std::forward can produce different code in this example. Up to now I have always used std::forward in combination with universal references as Yongwei Wu points out correctly.

Comment: This looks pretty good to me. The big question now is: Does this do what you want it to do? That is a question only the class designer can answer, and not me or anyone else. You've well demonstrated what it does. Nice job.

Comment: @YongweiWu: If the first constructor was changed as you suggest, one should also constrain the `U` so that `std::is_constructible<Wrapper<T>, U>{}` gives the right answer, whatever that right answer is.  If left unconstrained, the answer is always true, which is almost certainly the wrong answer.

Comment: For questions about why move/forward are behaving the way they do, there are lots of SO question/answers that address this.  Just search around a bit.  Here's one that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9671749/576911  Here's a brief tutorial: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html

Comment: Thanks, those were good pointers.  I've also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616958/stdforward-without-perfect-forwarding) very similar question (using `std::forward` without perfect forwarding) helpful.

Comment: @HowardHinnant You are completely right. I thought about this, but I forgot the details. @5gon12eder You can check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831382/capturing-perfectly-forwarded-variable-in-lambda, which has a good example of using `std::enable_if` to restrict the type that can be used to invoke the the wrapper constructor. You should use that to improve your answer.