# Usage of std::forward vs std::move

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding, stdmove

I always read that `std::forward` is only for use with template parameters. However, I was asking myself why. See the following example:

```
void ImageView::setImage(const Image& image){
    _image = image;
}

void ImageView::setImage(Image&& image){
    _image = std::move(image);
}
```

Those are two functions which basically do the same; one takes an l-value reference, the other an r-value reference. Now, I thought since `std::forward` is supposed to return an l-value reference if the argument is an l-value reference and an r-value reference if the argument is one, this code could be simplified to something like this:

```
void ImageView::setImage(Image&& image){
    _image = std::forward(image);
}
```

Which is kind of similar to the example cplusplus.com mentions for `std::forward` (just without any template parameters). I'd just like to know, if this is correct or not, and if not why.

I was also asking myself what exactly would be the difference to

```
void ImageView::setImage(Image& image){
    _image = std::forward(image);
}
```

Comment: To really understand, watch this video: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11

Comment: Problem: Forward does _not_ return an lvalue reference or rvalue reference depending on it's parameter.  In fact, it ignores the value-category of the parameter altogether.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between std::move and std::forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671749/whats-the-difference-between-stdmove-and-stdforward)

Comment: When it is not a template parameter, the && means an rvalue (and not a forwarding ref), and thus following the [binding rules (see the table here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47734382/c-how-does-the-compiler-decide-between-overloaded-functions-with-reference-t/47736813#47736813) which means lvalue ref to `Image` cannot be bounded to `Image&&`.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You *cannot* use `std::forward` without explicitly specifying its template argument. It is intentionally used in a non-deduced context.

To understand this, you need to really understand how forwarding references (`T&&` for a deduced `T`) work internally, and not wave them away as "it's magic." So let's look at that.

```
template <class T>
void foo(T &&t)
{
  bar(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

Let's say we call `foo` like this:

```
foo(42);
```

- `42` is an rvalue of type `int`.
- `T` is deduced to `int`.
- The call to `bar` therefore uses `int` as the template argument for `std::forward`.
- The return type of `std::forward<U>` is `U &&` (in this case, that's `int &&`) so `t` is forwarded as an rvalue.

Now, let's call `foo` like this:

```
int i = 42;
foo(i);
```

- `i` is an lvalue of type `int`.
- Because of the special rule for perfect forwarding, when an lvalue of type `V` is used to deduce `T` in a parameter of type `T &&`, `V &` is used for deduction. Therefore, in our case, `T` is deduced to be `int &`.

Therefore, we specify `int &` as the template argument to `std::forward`. Its return type will therefore be "`int & &&`", which collapses to `int &`. That's an lvalue, so `i` is forwarded as an lvalue.

**Summary**

Why this works with templates is when you do `std::forward<T>`, `T` is sometimes a reference (when the original is an lvalue) and sometimes not (when the original is an rvalue). `std::forward` will therefore cast to an lvalue or rvalue reference as appropriate.

You cannot make this work in the non-template version precisely because you'll have only one type available. Not to mention the fact that `setImage(Image&& image)` would not accept lvalues at all—an lvalue cannot bind to rvalue references.

Comment: Ok, I think I understood that so far.
What I was wondering: I can call a function `template <typename T> void foo(T&& t)` with l-value references as well as with r-value references? And in case it's an lvalue reference T is deduced as `V&`, which means the arguments type becomes `(V& &&)`, which is basically an rvlaue reference to an lvalue reference (or what?)? So this is a point where the behaviour differs from non-template functions, where a function `void foo(MyType&& t)` can only be called with r-value references?

Comment: @user1488118 There are reference collapsing rules. `T && &&` collapses to `T &&`, all others (`T & &&` , `T && &` and `T & &`) collapse to `T &`. --- Yes, the deduction of `V&` is what allows you to call the function template with both lvalues and rvalues (not necessarily references). A non-template function taking `Image&&` can only be called with rvalues of type `Image`.

Comment: Ok. If I declared my function as `template <typename T> void foo(T& t)` what would T then be deduced to for calls like `foo(42)` or `int i = 42; foo(i);`?

Comment: `foo(i)` would deduce `T` as `int`. `foo(42)` [wouldn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46e3f0077c495103), because 42 is an rvalue and cannot bind to a non-const lvalue reference. The special rule of using `V &` instead of `V` only applies when the type of the function parameter is `T &&` for a template parameter `T`. Anything else causes the rule to not apply.

Comment: Ok. Just a question regarding the behaviour of `std::forward`: From what I understand from your post: a call `std::forward<int>(i)` would have a return value of type `int&&`, `std::forward<int&>(i)` would have a return of type `int&`, and `std::forward<int&&>(i)` would have a return of type `int&&`? If we now exchange `i` with the literal `42`, would it be the same? The documentation states: "[std::forward] Returns an rvalue reference to arg if arg is not an lvalue reference. If arg is an lvalue reference, the function returns arg without modifying its type." It doesn't say anything about <T>.

Comment: @user1488118 Which "documentation"? Cplusplus.com? That site is not known for its accuracy, quite the opposite. Prefer [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward). Either way, the only authoritative source of "documentation" is the standard, which specifies it as I've described in my answer.

Comment: "std::forward will therefore cast to an lvalue of rvalue reference as appropriate."  I think you meant to say: std::forward will therefore cast to an lvalue OR rvalue reference as appropriate.   I only bring this up as I could see someone getting confused who doesn't understand how it works

Comment: @bjackfly Thanks, typo fixed.

Comment: Would it make sense to use the simplified version (using forward without templates) mentioned in the question if you know that the function will always receive only rvalue as parameters?

Comment: @AbhishekBhagate As the answer says, there *is no such simplified version.* `std::forward` is (intentionally) implemented in a way which prevents template argument deduction on its argument - you *cannot* call it without specifying the template argument explicitly.

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO From your post, I can understand that using forward with template argument helps in forwarding accordingly based on whether `T` is lvalue or rvalue. But consider, I have a case where the function takes only one type and that is known to be always an rvalue & the function simply forwards the parameter.  Then I don't see why it isn't possible in this case to use a function that takes a parameter as `myType&& param` and use `anotherFun(forward<myType>(param))`. Doesn't this achieve the purpose desired in this case? Why would I need to use template argument in this case?

Comment: @AbhishekBhagate If you're accepting rvalue references only, then the thing to use is not `std::forward<T>`, but `std::move`.

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO Thanks! I got the point

Answer (score 44):

I recommend reading "Effective Modern C ++" by **Scott Meyers**, specifically:

- **Item 23**: Understand `std::move` and `std::forward`.
- **Item 24**: Distinguish universal references for rvalue references.

> From a purely technical perspective, the answer is yes: **`std::forward`
> can do it all.** `std::move` isn’t necessary. Of course, neither function
> is really necessary, because we could write casts everywhere, but I
> hope we agree that that would be, well, yucky. **`std::move`’s attractions
> are convenience, reduced likelihood of error, and greater clarity**.

### rvalue-reference

This function accepts rvalues and cannot accept lvalues.

```
void ImageView::setImage(Image&& image){
    _image = std::forward(image);        // error 
    _image = std::move(image);           // conventional
    _image = std::forward<Image>(image); // unconventional
}
```

Note first that `std::move` requires only a function argument, while `std::forward` requires both a function argument and a template type argument.

### Universal references (forwarding references)

This function accepts all and does perfect forwarding.

```
template <typename T> void ImageView::setImage(T&& image){
    _image = std::forward<T>(image);
}
```

Comment: N.B. the official name for "universal reference" is now _forwarding reference_

Comment: @JonathanWakely: _"the official name for "universal reference" is now forwarding reference"_ - I didn't get the memo. Since when? Where was it announced? Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: It's defined in this proposal (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4164.pdf) but is that accepted in a recent standard draft?

Comment: @JohannGerell Herb Sutter also talked about it on CppCon 2014, and the latest edition of Effective C++ mentions it as well, IIRR.

Comment: @JonathanWakely There's a [tag:universal-reference] tag. Would you happen to have a link which we could use to update the wiki?

Comment: @JohannGerell, yes, for example see the current draft, [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)

Comment: @Angew, the N4164 link above?

Comment: Thanks, for reference, _forwarding reference_ is defined in §14.8.2.3 of [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)

Comment: As a note, the universal reference example should _probably_ constrain the template parameter, to make sure it's always `Image`.  Considering that the question was asked about C++11, the appropriate way to do so would be by adding something like, e.g., `static_assert(std::is_same<std::decay<T>::type, Image>::value, "Must be called with an Image.");`.

Answer (score 10):

You have to specify the template type in `std::forward`.

In this context `Image&& image` is *always* an r-value reference and `std::forward<Image>` will always move so you might as well use `std::move`.

Your function accepting an r-value reference cannot accept l-values so it is not equivalent to the first two functions.

Comment: `std::forward` will move only if used as `std::forward<Image>`, or `std::forward<Image&&>`, not *always* as you say

Comment: @PiotrS. You are right, I was oversimplifying. Hopefully that is better.