# Working of std::forward and reference collapsing

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding, reference-collapsing

I am trying to familiarize myself with the concept of perfect forwarding.
I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526598/how-does-stdforward-work) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501400/the-implementation-of-stdforward) post here. I believe I am also comfortable with the reference collapsing concept. While reading this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828159/usage-of-stdforward-vs-stdmove)  post. I came up with the following question

Suppose we have the following example

```
Example-1
template <class T>
void foo(T &&t)
{
  bar(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

and we pass it something like this

```
int i= 12;
foo(i);
```

Now I understand this `i` will be treated as a `int&` what I don't understand
is why does the answered question in the above link mention that it will be
treated as `int& &&` which will collapse as `int&.` I am of the opinion that it will be treated as `int&& &` which will collapse to `int&` **I understand the return type of both is the same but I would like to get the first part right.
The reason why I think it is `int&& &` instead of `int& &&` is mentioned below please correct me if I am wrong**

When I pass in something like this

```
int i =12;
foo(i);
```

Then Example 1 becomes something like this

```
void foo(int &&t)
{
  bar(std::forward<int>(&t)); // t is a reference now ------>A
}
```

Now std::forward implementation is this

```
template<typename T>                // For lvalues (T is T&),
T&& std::forward(T&& param)         // take/return lvalue refs.
{                                   // For rvalues (T is T),
    return static_cast<T&&>(param); // take/return rvalue refs.
}
```

so when our solution is applied to it . It becomes

```
return static_cast<int&&>(&param) ; //&param since we passed &t in A
```

we get

```
int&& & and not `int& &&` please correct me if I am wrong
```

Comment: is `&t` in `std::forward` a typo ?

Comment: `&t` forms a pointer, not a reference

Comment: and your implementation of `std::forward` is wrong

Comment: Do you mean the implementation that I posted or `return static_cast<int&&>(&param) ` ? I got that from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501400/the-implementation-of-stdforward

Comment: I mean there are two overloads for `std::forward`, one forcing an lvalue reference, and another forcing an rvalue reference

Comment: In response to your (deleted) question - yes, `T` can be deduced as a reference type only when a parameter type is a forwarding reference, `T&&`. (Note: if `T` is a type template parameter, then `T&&` is **not an rvalue reference**, but a *forwarding-reference*)

Comment: YEs I figured that part out thus I deleted the question. Thanks for replying though.

Comment: Saying references are pointers behind the scenes is like sayimg when you draw a route on a map, behind the scenes you are flying a plane with a huge paint sprayer and putting a line on what the map represents.  One way to implement references is with pointers, but saying references are pointers is confusing the territory for the map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass `i` as an argument to `foo`:

```
int i = 12;
foo(i);
```

expression `i` has an lvalue category, thus `T` is deduced as `int&`, so example 1 becomes:

```
void foo<int&>(int& && t) // `int& t` due to reference collapsing
//         |   \ /
//         +--> T  = int&
{//                   V
    bar(std::forward<int&>(t));
}
```

Now, in `std::forward`, the `param`'s type is specified explicitly to be `int&`, so:

```
int& && std::forward<int&>(typename std::remove_reference<int&>::type& param)
//                    ^~~+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
//                       |
{//                      V          
    return static_cast<int& &&>(param); // `int&` due to reference collapsing
}
```

which restores the lvalue category of `i`.

---

To make it clear, this is what happens when the argument expression's value category is an rvalue:

```
foo(12); // -> foo<int>(12);
//                  |
//        v~~~~~~~~~+
void foo<int>(int && t) // `int&& t`
//        |   \ /
//        +--> T  =  int
{//                   V
    bar(std::forward<int>(t));
}//                   |
//                    V 
int && std::forward<int>(typename std::remove_reference<int>::type& param)
//                    ^~~+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
//                       |
{//                      V          
    return static_cast<int &&>(param); // `int&&`
}
```

And when the type template parameter is specified as `int&&` explicitly:

```
foo<int&&>(12);
//     ^~~~+
//         V
void foo<int&&>(int&& && t) // `int&& t` due to reference collapsing
//         |    \   /
//         |     \ /
//         +----> T = int&&
{//                    V
    bar(std::forward<int&&>(t));
}//                    |
//                     V 
int&& && std::forward<int&&>(typename std::remove_reference<int&&>::type& param)
//                     ^~~+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
//                        |
{//                       V          
    return static_cast<int&& &&>(param); // `int&&` due to reference collapsing
}
```