# C++ - How does the compiler decide between overloaded functions with reference types as parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion, overloading

While studying C++ I have come across the complex topic of conversion sequences and I have encountered a problem that I couldn't solve on my own.

```
void g(const double)
{
    std::cout << "void g(const double)" << std::endl;
}

void g(const double&&)
{
    std::cout << "void g(const double&&)" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    g(3.14);    
    return (0);
}
```

---------------------------- Second example ----------------------------

```
void g(const double)
{
    std::cout << "void g(const double)" << std::endl;
}

void g(const double&)
{
    std::cout << "void g(const double&)" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    g(3.14);    
    return (0);
}
```

In this two examples the compiler complains about the fact that the call of the overloaded function "g(double)" is ambiguous.

```
void g(const double&&)
{
    std::cout << "void g(const double&&)" << std::endl;
}

void g(const double&)
{
    std::cout << "void g(const double&)" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    g(3.14);    
    return (0);
}
```

But in this example the program compiles properly and prints out "void g(const double&&)".
So I don't get why the compiler complains about the first two examples but doesn't about the third.

Comment: Do you realize that `void g(const double)` is the same as `void g(double)` for overload resolution purposes? I am not fully sure but I think `void g(const double&&)` is the same as `void g(double&&)` too\.

Comment: A literal like 3.14 [is an rvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). In overloaded context, passing an rvalue as an rvalue reference is preferred to passing an rvalue as a constant reference. Passing as a constant reference is considered to be "worse" than passing as an rvalue reference, or by value, or as a constant reference. But passing by value, as an rvalue reference, or as a constant reference is considered to be "equal" in terms of preference, hence the ambiguity. That's the short, capsule summary version.

Comment: @RSahu the latter two are not the same (only one of them can accept xvalue of type `const double`)

Comment: @M.M, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: In principle, once you have a function receiving an object by value, say `void f(T)`, and you decide to overload `f` to be able to take such object by reference, say `void f(T&)` - You will create rooms for ambiguities to arise during overload resolution. You generally want to avoid such API's. You generally want to overload based on *rvalue* and *(const) lvalue* references or just pass *by value*, but not both.

Answer (score 4):

### Overload resolution table

This table summarizes who can go where:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               Caller    |   lvalue     | const lvalue |   rvalue     | const rvalue 
         Function        |              |              |              |  
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a]  f(X& x)         |    V (1)     |              |              |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [b]  f(const X& x)   |    V (2)     |      V       |    V (3)     |    V (2)
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [c]  f(X&& x)        |              |              |    V (1)     |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [d]  f(const X&& x)  |              |              |    V (2)     |    V (1)
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- All the above signatures can live together.
- The **V** sign marks the possible valid resolutions
- When there is more than one valid resolution for the same caller they are numbered, (1) being a better match than (2) etc.
- There is no sense in overloading byval version with any of the above, unless having additional difference such as const on the method etc.
  Adding a byvalue version: f(X x) would not work well with any combination of the above - in most cases it would result with an *ambiguity* for any call, for some cases it would just prefer the byval version (if it lives only with [a] -  any call except lvalue would prefer the byvalue version and an lvalue call would result with an *ambiguity*).
- Signature [d] is rarely used, see: [Do rvalue references to const have any use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938875/do-rvalue-references-to-const-have-any-use)

Answer (score 3):

In overload resolution, direct reference binding is an *identity conversion* (even if qualifiers are added); it's no better or worse for a `double` to match a parameter of `double` or reference-to-`double`.

The `const` is somewhat of a red herring in your examples. For a non-reference type, `f(const double)`, the top-level `const` is not part of the function signature; and in `f(const double&)`,  it is still direct binding and so still the identity conversion.

So, your first 2 cases are both identity conversions in both cases and no reason to prefer one or the other.

In case 3, rule C++14 [over.ics.rank]/3.1.3 applies:

> Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence
>   S2 if
>
> - [...]
> - S1 and S2 are reference bindings (8.5.3) and neither refers to an implicit object parameter of a
>     non-static member function declared without a ref-qualifier, and S1 binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue and S2 binds an lvalue reference.

This rule allows functions to be overloaded for rvalues and lvalues of the same type.