# VStudio 2012 Create custom allocator for container of move-only type

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2012, stl, allocator

I am trying to create an stl container of a move-only type that uses its own allocator in VStudio 2012.

The trouble is: it seems as though I have to provide a construct function for the allocator which in turn needs access to a public copy constructor on the contained type.

I either get:

error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'

or

error C2039: 'construct' : is not a member of 'MyAllocator'

The same code works in clang so I suspect the problem is due to Microsoft but can anyone suggest a possible work around?

This is my code for minimal reproduction

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template< typename T>
struct MyAllocator
{
typedef T value_type;
typedef value_type*         pointer;
typedef value_type&         reference;
typedef const value_type*   const_pointer;
typedef const value_type&   const_reference;
typedef size_t              size_type;
typedef ptrdiff_t           difference_type;


template<class t_other>
struct rebind
{
    typedef MyAllocator<t_other> other;
};

MyAllocator():m_id(0) {}
MyAllocator(int id):m_id(id){}

template <class T> 
MyAllocator(const MyAllocator<T>& other)
    :m_id(other.getId())
{

}  

T* allocate(std::size_t n)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(malloc(sizeof(T) * n));
}

void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n)
{
    free(p);
}

int getId() const{ return m_id;}


//Have to add these although should not be necessary
void construct(pointer mem, const_reference value)
{
    std::_Construct(mem, value);      
}

void destroy(pointer mem)
{
    std::_Destroy(mem);
}

private:
    int m_id;
};

template <class T1, class U>
bool operator==(const MyAllocator<T1>& lhs, const MyAllocator<U>& rhs)
{
    return lhs.getId() == rhs.getId() ;
}

template <class T1, class U>
bool operator!=(const MyAllocator<T1>&, const MyAllocator<U>&)
{
    return lhs.getId()  != rhs.getId();
}

//define a move only type
typedef unique_ptr<uint32_t> MyIntPtr;

//define a container based on MyIntPtr and MyAllocator
typedef vector<MyIntPtr, MyAllocator<MyIntPtr> > MyVector;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   MyAllocator<MyIntPtr> alloc1(1);

   MyVector vec(alloc1);

   uint32_t* rawPtr = new uint32_t;
   *rawPtr = 18;

   vec.emplace_back(rawPtr);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which is the clang version that you compiled this with? http://gcc.godbolt.org seems to show different results - compilation with clang fails as well.

Comment: Have `construct` take `T&&` as the second parameter, and move from it. Even more generally, under C++11 `construct` is supposed to take an arbitrary set of arguments, and execute an equivalent of `new(p) T(std::forward(args))` (not sure if VC12 supports C++11 sufficiently well to allow this). This is necessary to support `emplace` and similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is because you try to construct a [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) from a constant reference to a `std::unique_ptr` of the same type - and there is no such constructor.

You can rework your `construct` method to take an an rvalue reference and then everything compiles nicely:

```
void construct(pointer mem, value_type&& value)
{
    std::_Construct(mem, std::move(value));      
}
```

Comment: should it not be std::_Construct(mem, std::move(value)); ?

Comment: or  
     template< typename T3 >
     void construct(pointer mem, T3&& value)
     {
         std::_Construct(mem, std::forward<T3>(value));
     }

Both seem to work

Comment: Actually the move vs forward here got me thinking a bit - I edited the answer 3 times:D Well as per my understanding forward seems more appropriate since you want to forward the value as is after the reference collapsing but I may be wrong and if someone demonstrates how move is superior in this case I'll happily edit:) I'm still not that strong with C++11 but as per my understanding forward seems to be more appropriate here.

Comment: I thought std::forward only had one use case and that was to forward the universal reference you got with a template.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671749/whats-the-difference-between-stdmove-and-stdforward

Comment: @DavidWoo maybe I am wrong but since the value type can have different constructors shouldn't perfect forwarding be required in this case? Again, not 100% sure.

Comment: @DavidWoo ok but since you want a move-only type you actually want to escape any lvalue reference ctors so I guess my initial reasoning was wrong and move is more appropriate:) Thank you for the question, this actually made me learn a bit more.

Comment: You are right that perfect forwarding should be used and the general case is that construct should be a variadic template method since C++11 (which VS2012 does not support). Your code currently just takes an rvalue reference and as such should use move.