# std::move Vs std::forward

Tags: c++, c++11, move, perfect-forwarding

This seems to be most relavant question already asked.

[Whats the difference between std::move and std::forward](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9671749/14065)

But each answer is different and applies and says slightly different things. So I am confused.

I have the following situation.

- **Copy item into container**
  The Copy item is C++03 so I understand that quite well.
- **Construct item into container**
  The Construct item into container I believe uses perfect forwarding correctly to forward the arguments through two functions to the constructor of T in `emplaceBackInternal()` (Please say otherwise if I am wrong).
- **Move item into container**
  My problem seems to be understanding the moving an item into the container.

The Code:

```
template<typename T>
class Container
{
    std::size_t length;
    T*          buffer;

public:
    void push_back(T const& value)
    {
         resizeIfRequired();
         pushBackInternal(value);
    }
    template<typename... Args>
    void emplace_back(Args&&... args)
    {
         resizeIfRequired();
         emplaceBackInternal(std::forward<T>(arg)...);
    }
    void push_back(T&& value)
    {
         resizeIfRequired();
         // Is this forward correct or should it be move
         moveBackInternal(std::forward<T>(value));
    }
private:
    void pushBackInternal(T const& value)
    {
         // Copy construct object into buffer;
         new (buffer + length) T(value);
         ++length;
    }
    template<typename... Args)
    void emplaceBackInternal(Args&&... args)
    {
         // Construct object into buffer using arguments;
         new (buffer + length) T(std::forward<T>(args)...);
         ++length;
    }
    void moveBackInternal(T&& value)
    {
         // Move construct object into buffer;
         // Is this forward correct or should it be move
         new (buffer + length) T(std::forward<T>(value));
         ++length;
    }
};
```

I include all three here to compare the three functions with the answers provided in the previously mentioned answer. The main reason is that `move` and `construct` looks so similar that it feels like they should be the same.

[Answer @Potatoswatter Score 67](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9716708/14065)

> std::forward has a single use case: to cast a **templated function parameter**

By this definition I should be using `std::move` inside `push_back(T&& value)` and 
`moveBackInternal(T&& value)` as the value is not a template parameter for the function.

[Answer @Howard Hinnant Score 38](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9672202/14065)

> If Y is an lvalue reference, the result will be an lvalue expression. **If Y is not an lvalue reference, the result will be an rvalue** (xvalue to be precise) expression.

Seems by this definition I can use either `std::move` or `std::forward`.

[Answer @Bo Persson Score 11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671852/14065)

> std::forward is used to forward a parameter exactly the way it was passed to a function.

Seems to say that `std::forward` is acceptable (though if I follow the link in the answer all the examples use templated functions).

Comment: Er... what's your question that wasn't answered by the linked answers?

Comment: Er... which answer is correct!. Each one specifies a different result.

Comment: They're all correct. Two just say the intent of `std::forward` is for forwarding references and the third additionally spends some time explain what `std::forward` is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case:

```
void push_back(T&& value)
{
     resizeIfRequired();
     moveBackInternal(std::forward<T>(value));  // (1)             
     moveBackInternal(std::move(value));        // (2) 

}
```

`std::forward<T>(value)` and `std::move(value)` are **identical** in this scenario (it doesn't matter between `(1)` and `(2)`... so use `(2)`).

`move` is an unconditional cast to xvalue. That line gives you an expression of type `T&&` that's an rvalue, always.

`forward` is a conditional cast. If `T` is an lvalue reference type, it yields an lvalue. Otherwise (if it's either not a reference type or an rvalue reference type), it yields an rvalue. In our case, `T` is not a reference type - so we get an rvalue.

Either way, we end up at the same point - we call `moveBackInternal` with `value` cast as an rvalue. Just `move()` is a simpler way of getting there. `forward<T>` *works*, but it's unnecessary.

Comment: Its at times like this I wish I was in an office with you (or the author of a post) and could have a frank discussion with a whiteboard as to the better technique. -- If I make the assumption that at all the work done by both `std::move` and `std::forward` is compile time work. Then would not solution (1) be better because it makes the code look identical to `emplace_back()`. Why do I need two different techniques when I could have one technique that worked in all situations? Less differences means easier to maintain code?

Comment: @LokiAstari Seems primarily opinion based. I find it more straightforward to use `move()` when we're moving unconditionally. The `push_back()` code only ever moves, so why use the more complicated cast? Ultimately, I find there's something fundamentally... off... with forwarding references. I don't know how it could be done better - and for better or for worse, this is what we got.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. To be honest I am still trying to form my opinion and just trying to play devils advocate here. :-)