# Why use std::forward rather than std::move for data member in rvalue reference constructor's initialization list?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I have read these materials:

[What's the difference between std::move and std::forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671749/whats-the-difference-between-stdmove-and-stdforward)

[std::move Vs std::forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142355/stdmove-vs-stdforward)

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28828689/6949852) is very close to my question, but one is `setImage`, the other is rvalue reference constructor, so I'm afraid something subtle exists.

## Forward

```
class ClassRoom
{
private:
    vector<string> students;

public:
    ClassRoom(vector<string>&& theStudents)
        :students{std::forward<vector<string>>(theStudents)}
    {
    }
}
```

## Move

```
class ClassRoom
{
private:
    vector<string> students;

public:
    ClassRoom(vector<string>&& theStudents)
        :students{std::move(theStudents)}
    {
    }
}
```

Someone told me `forward` is the right method here because one of the usages of `forward` is to pass rvalue reference variable to others and guarantee not use it again.  but I can't figure out why not to use `move` here and is what he said right?

Comment: The answer is: don't. Use `std::forward` when you want to perfect forward a deduced parameter (template/auto) - this **may** become equivalent to `std::move` (when the deduced parameter is an rvalue reference). Use `std::move` when you want to move from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this example, both `std::move` and `std::forward` do the same thing.

This is different if you change the example to a deduced type, e.g.

```
template<typename Arg>
ClassRoom(Arg&& theStudents)
    :students{std::forward<Arg>(theStudents)}
{
}
```

v.s.

```
template<typename Arg>
ClassRoom(Arg&& theStudents)
    :students{std::move(theStudents)}
{
}
```

Then:

```
vector<string> local_students = /* ... */;
ClassRoom cr(local_students)
```

`Arg` deduces to `vector<string>&`, which means different things happen

Forward:

`forward<vector<string>&>` passes along the lvalue-reference, so the overload of `vector::vector` chosen is the copy constructor, `local_students` is unaffected

Move:

`move<vector<string>&>` casts the lvalue-reference to rvalue-reference, so the overload of `vector::vector` chosen is the move constructor, `local_students` is now in the moved-from state

Comment: do you really need a variadic template here?

Comment: It's a reasonable example of propagating all different arities of `vector::vector`

Comment: it's excessive in this example as it's based on original one with only one parameter, and so can confuse readers to think `std::forward` makes sense only with variadic templates

Comment: @Gruffalo: that's a valid remark. When I was learning this stuff, I made this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `std::move` here. `std::forward` is intended to forward universal references. There is no universal references in this case. 
Although in this example it'll be no difference, `std::move` is more concise and more self documenting.