# How to use lambda expressions in own method

Tags: c++, qt, lambda

I like the new syntax for [QObject::connect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qobject.html#connect-4)

```
connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged, [=](const QString &newValue) {
    receiver->updateValue("senderValue", newValue);
});
```

I want to implement my own method that gets a lambda expression as argument.

In my particular case I want to recreate the Javascript Function [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

**How does the correct syntax look like to have a lambda as argument of my method?** I want the lambda not to have any arguments or another return type than void.

```
void setTimeout(/* SOME_TYPE callback */, int timeout)
{
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setInterval(timeout);
    timer->setSingleShot(true);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, (){
        //This lambda should be an argument
    });
    //connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, callback);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, timer, &QObject::deleteLater);
    timer->start();
}
```

I can't find the methods defined in QObject. Some are only defined for documentation generation. (`#ifdef Q_QDOC`)

Comment: `template <typename Callback> void setTimeout(Callback callback, int timeout) { connect(..., callback);}`

Comment: Do you want to allow a lambda that has captured?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: that's indeed the best *as long as* you don't have to take it in a virtual function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to reimplement it: `QTimer::singleShot` does it all.

If you wanted to wrap `singleShot` or `connect`, you don't really care what the callable is, as long as target method accepts it. There's no reason for `onTimeout` to be a class member. It should be a free function: we're writing C++, not Java.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/forward-callable-38126723
#include <QtCore>

template <typename C>
void onTimeout(int msec, C && callable) {
   QTimer::singleShot(msec, std::forward<C>(callable));
}

template <typename C>
void onTimeout(int msec, QObject * context, C && callable) {
   QTimer::singleShot(msec, context, std::forward<C>(callable));
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QCoreApplication app{argc, argv};
   QObject context;
   QThread thread;
   context.moveToThread(&thread);
   thread.start();
   onTimeout(1000, []{ qDebug() << "T+1s"; });
   onTimeout(2000, &context, [&]{ qDebug() << "T+2s"; thread.quit(); });
   QObject::connect(&thread, &QThread::finished, &app, &QCoreApplication::quit);
   return app.exec();
}
```

The first timeout is handled from the main thread's event loop. The second timeout is handled from the worker thread's event loop - that's what the `context` argument is for. When implementing a function/method that accepts a callable, you should always optionally accept a context object that dictates what thread the callable will execute in. The default is to execute it in the event loop of the current thread.

See also [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9671749/1329652) about the purpose of `std::forward`.

Answer (score 0):

You might either have `template<typename T>` and take `const T&`, which has the advantage of being quick an working with functors, too - or you might use `std::function<>`, which is a bit slower but can be taken by a virtual function as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make the parameter that should accept the lambda of the appropriate template type `std::function<Res(Arg,...)>' from the header`functional`.