# Confusion between std::move and std::forward

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmove

So I was just writing a sample and contrived example of `std::forward` for my understanding, but it didn't work the way I expected. In the program below

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(const std::string& m) : m_(m) {};
    std::string m_;
};

template<typename T>
void funcB(T&& obj)  // universal reference
{
    std::string local = std::move(obj.m_);   // using std::move on universal reference. Bad.
    std::cout << "funcB : " << local << '\n';
}

template<typename T>
void funcC(T&& obj)  // universal reference
{
    std::string local = std::forward<std::string>(obj.m_);   // using std::move on universal reference
    std::cout << "funcC : " << local << '\n';
}

template<typename T>
void funcD(T&& obj)  // universal reference
{
    T local = std::forward<T>(obj);   // using std::move on universal reference
    std::cout << "funcD : " << local.m_ << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    A obj("firstString");

   //funcA(obj);  // We get compiler error. Rvalue reference cannot be bound to Lvalue
    funcB(obj);  
    std::cout << "Main : " <<  obj.m_ << '\n';

    A obj2("secondString");
    funcC(obj2);
    std::cout << "Main : " << obj2.m_ << '\n';

    A obj3("thirdString");
    funcD(obj3);
    std::cout << "Main : " << obj3.m_ << '\n';
}
```

In the output

```
funcB : firstString
Main : 
funcC : secondString
Main : 
funcD : thirdString
Main : thirdString
```

In `funcC`, even though I have used universal references and here it is bound to Lvalue, the string is moved when I do `std::forward<std::string>`. Hence the in the last line, after "Main:" there is no output. Can someone please how the string is moved even though obj is bound to Lvalue.

Just realized the answer to this, after rereading a book.

In funcC, `std::forward<std::string>(obj.m_)` is equivalent to moving the string.
But in funcD, `std::forward` is instantiated as `std::forward<struct A&>(obj)`, which is copied.

Comment: By the way, now it is called *forwarding reference*, not *universal reference*.

Comment: Since C++17 is it ?

Comment: @avi007: [Basically, yes](https://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-complete.html#147), although aside from the standard this has been the common terminology for a few years now. The only actual standard change is to _add_ this name (the old name was never in there) so you can probably safely apply the newly-popular terminology when discussing code compliant to any of the standards since C++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases you are constructing a string, `std::string local`, with an rvalue reference as argument. As a result, `local` is move-constructed from the original object referred-to by that reference.

This doesn't have much to do with `std::forward` or with `std::move`; furthermore, you are not initialising a reference (which is where "binding *a reference* to an lvalue" comes from in Meyers's text; the reference would be on the LHS) — you are simply constructing an object from another object.

However, it is true that without writing `std::forward` or `std::move` you would end up *copying* those function arguments instead, as the rvalue reference would be dropped on the initialisation side of `local`'s declaration.

So, in this case, `std::forward` and `std::move` have the same effect. However, they are not the same thing and should generally not be treated as interchangeable. Read the following for more information:

- [What's the difference between std::move and std::forward](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9671749/560648)

Comment: Don't mean to be upfront. But I'm currently studying Effective modern C++. I can see phrases like "binding to an lvalue" and "binding to rvalue" almost everywhere in chapter 5.  obj in funcC is universal reference, and I'm passing obj2 in main. So it is getting instantiated with normal reference i.e Lvalue.

Comment: @avi007: Okay, assuming Meyers, I see where you're getting that from. The book is referring to binding references to lvalues, i.e. initialising references from lvalues. Not the other way around (which I maintain doesn't exist). I've tweaked my answer a little to clarify.

Comment: I have just added funcD, and it's corresponding output in the question. Could you please comment on how it's different from funcC.

Comment: Just going through, Effective Modern C++ again. So according to Item 28, in funcD, forward<T> is instantiated as forward<struct A&>, so the output makes sense. Thanks Lightness Races in Orbit