# std::forward acting differently

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I'm currently learning perfect forwarding in c++ and I came across something that confused me. Pretty sure it's something stupid. When I used std::forward on a lvalue, it used the rvalue function. This is a pretty bad explanation so I'm just gonna show the code.

```
#include <iostream>

void check(int&& other) {
    std::cout << "Rvalue" << std::endl;
}

void check(int& other) {
    std::cout << "Lvalue" << std::endl;
}

void call(int& other) {
    check(std::forward<int>(other));
}

int main()
{
    int i = 4;
    call(i);
}
```

This outputs "Rvalue". Please help me understand why.

Comment: The _only_ reason to use `std::forward` is on a method that accepts universal template references `template<T> void func(T&& other)`. That being said, this question is well written and worth answering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between std::move and std::forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671749/whats-the-difference-between-stdmove-and-stdforward) There's an answer of mine there where I make the same explanation steps for `std::forward` and `std::move`, which I think gives a lot of insight on both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Perfect forwarding" is used in ***templates***, i.e.:

```
template<typename T>
void func(T && arg)
{
    func2(std::forward<T>(arg));
}
```

Outside of template context the end result drastically changes. All that `std::forward` does is [return `static_cast<T &&>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward), so your `call` function becomes nothing more than:

```
void call(int& other) {
    check(static_cast<int &&>(other));
}
```

Hence you get an *rvalue*. The reason this works differently in templates is because a `&&` template parameter is a ***forwarding reference*** (a fancy term for either an lvalue or an rvalue-deduced reference, depending on what gets dropped in that parameter), and because of [reference collapsing rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference). Briefly, when used in a template context, the end result is:

1. `T` gets deduced as either an lvalue or an rvalue reference, depending on what the parameter is.
2. The result of the `static_cast<T &&>` is an lvalue reference, if `T` is an lvalue reference, or an rvalue reference if `T` is an rvalue reference, due to reference collapsing rules.

The end result is that the same kind of a reference gets forwarded. But this only works in template context, since it requires both forwarding reference semantics and reference collapsing rules to work *just right*.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::forward()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) isn't exactly magic. Which is one of the reasons one has to give it the appropriate type with the appropriate reference-category (rvalue-reference, lvalue-reference, no reference).

Normally, you get the type from the template-argument. If it's an `auto&&`-argument (C++14 lambda, C++20 abbreviated template or use of concept), one uses `decltype()` to get it from the function-argument.

Manually specifying it works, but goes against the spirit of using the function. [`std::move()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) or the argument itself is much easier to use in that case, depending on the template-argument you specify.

And due to how reference-collapsing and `std::forward()` are defined, `Type` and `Type&&` both result in an rvalue-reference, while `Type&` results in an lvalue-reference.