# C++ Forwarding on variadic values which are not rvalue references

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

Consider:

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args... args) {
    bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename... Args>
void foo2(Args&&... args) {
    bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

I understand the perfect rvalue references forwarding in case of `foo2`, but what is the purpose of forwarding the variadic argument values of `foo`?

What would be different if `foo` would look like this?

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args... args) {
    bar(args...);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the same thing.

In this

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args... args) {
    bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

- `Args` will never be deduced to be a reference (`foo(Args...)` means `foo`'s taking the arguments by value, not by reference);
- on the other hand [`std::forward<T>(t)` is nothing more than `static_cast<T&&>(t)`, just with a more explicit intent from the programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65446786/5825294);

The two things together sum up to `static_cast<Args&&>(args)...` having an rvalue reference return type, i.e. returning an rvalue (because `Args` is not a reference, so no reference collapsing can occur between `Args` and `&&` to give an lvalue reference return type, which would mean an lvalue return value).

So no, there's no perfect forwarding in your first version of `foo`. The `std::forward` in it unconditionally casts its arguments to rvalues; and that's typically `std::move`'s job:

```cpp
// this is equivalent to the code above
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args... args) {
    bar(std::move(args)...);
}
```