# Move constructor for derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization, move-semantics

I have 2 classes:

```
template<typename T>
class base{
    T t;
public:
    base(base &&b): t(std::move(b.t)){}
};

template<typename T, typename T2>
class derived : protected base<T>{
    T2 t2;
public:
    derived(derived &&d): base<T>(std::move(d)), t2(std::move(d.t2)){}
};
```

I move entire `d` object in the `derived` `move-constructor` to initialize `base` part and `d` becomes invalid but I still need it to use it's part for `t2` initialization

Is it possible to do such a thing?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that `t2(std::move(t2))` is either not going to compile, or is undefined behavior.

Comment: `base(std::move(d))` kinda looks like move-slicing. `base` only knows about `t` and only moves `t`, but this leaves you in an uncomfortable spot since after a move the object needs to be safely disposable, and at this point only `base` meets that requirement. Crom only knows what's in `derived::t2`. But this would be true of any derived object. You could never move a derived object and that's nuts. So long as after the move of `derived` is complete the `derived` can be disposed of, I think you're good to go. The `base` part of `d` is moved, then the `derived` part of `d` is moved.

Comment: `std::move` doesn't actually move anything, it's just a cast to rvalue reference. The move constructor is what actually modifies the data. And you know that, in your case, `base` move constructor is not going to invalidate `d.t2`. I believe your code is correct as written.

Comment: This is fine ... `base(std::move(d))` may cause the `base` portion of `d` to be "invalid" (whatever that may be, it could have been zero'ed etc) ... but the remainder of the derived type can still be accessed safely via `d.t2` ... the `base` move constructor won't have been able to touch it

Comment: Code should be correct as written, however, just for clarity, I would add `static_cast` to base for first move. This would signify the fact that only base part of the object was actually moved. This would not have any real effect on the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002627/c11-how-to-understand-the-function-move

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that your construct is correct except for a little syntax error, you need to qualify `base<T>` in the initializer list:

```
derived(derived &&d): base<T>(std::move(d)), t2(std::move(d.t2)){}
```

First, the order of initialization is independant of the order of the initializer list. Draft n4296 says in *12.6.2 Initializing bases and members [class.base.init] § 13*

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>   (13.1) — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in
>   the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes,
>   where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class base-specifier-list.
>   
> (13.2) — Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list
>   (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>   
> (13.3) — Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition
>   (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>   
> (13.4) — Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed.
>
> [ Note: The declaration order is mandated to ensure that base and member subobjects are destroyed in the
>   reverse order of initialization. —end note ]

We have also §7 or same chapter that says:

> The initialization performed by each mem-initializer constitutes a full-expression. Any
>   expression in a mem-initializer is evaluated as part of the full-expression that performs the initialization.

My understanding is that standard says that in the move ctor for the `derived` class, things happens in that order:

- move ctor for base class is called

  - in turn it calls move ctor for T effectively constructing t member of target and eventually zeroing t member of source
- move ctor for T2 object is called - at that moment, the end of the full expression has not been reached, and only t member of source has eventually been destroyed
- at the end of the full statement, source object is left in an undetermined state and should no longer be used.