# How to implement move-Constructors for derived classes with private members

Tags: c++, move, move-semantics

The following three goals leads to a conflict:

- I've learned, that `std::move` does nothing, but after
  `std::move(someDObject)` the Object `someDObject` may be canibalized and you should not access `someDObject`
- CleanCode-SingleResponsibiliPattern: a class should be responsible
  for just one Feature
- CodingStyle-DataEncapsulation: a class should not expose implementation details, even not to a derived class

Imagine a (not Copy-constructible) class with two distinct Feature. Cause of SRB one of them is realised in `Base` and second realised in `Derived : public Base`. Both classes hold their data in a movable Conainer like `std::list<std::string>`, called `m_dataDerived` and `m_dataBase` respectivly. Cause of DataEncapsulation `m_dataBase` should be `private:`.

This leads to the problem **how to implent the move-Constructor for the derived class**. Either:

```
Derived::Derived(Derived &&rhs)
: Base(std::move(rhs))
, m_dataDerived(std::move(rhs.m_dataDerived))
{}
```

This syntactically breaks rule one, not to access `rhs` after `std::move(rhs)` However `m_dataDerived` could not be canibalized by the Constructor of `Base`, since `Base` has no knowlege of it => hence `m_dataDerived` *should* be still valid. I do not like the *should*.

The other way round leads to other problems:

```
Derived::Derived(Derived &&rhs)
{
    m_dataBase = std::move(rhs.m_dataBase);
    m_dataDerived = std::move(rhs.m_dataDerived);
}
```

For this you need to consider `m_dataBase` as `protected:` what breaks DataEncapsulation. moreover every Change of `Base` must be done in all derived move-Contructors, what leads to a maintainance Problem.

**What is missing is some `std::move(`Only`Base`part of`rhs)`. Is there a way to do so?**

A Compiling Example of the first choice is on [onlineGdb](https://onlinegdb.com/r1cgdWb0H) (however with `std::vector` instead of `std::list`).

In addition the Code listed below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include  <algorithm>


class Base;

class Base {
public:
    Base() {};
    Base(Base &&rhs)  {
        std::cout << "BaseMove_Construktor(" << rhs.m_list.size() << ") --> " ;
        m_list = std::move(rhs.m_list);
       std::cout << m_list.size() <<  std::endl;
    }
    Base(std::initializer_list<std::string> &&p_list) {
        int i=0;
        m_list.resize(p_list.size());
        for(auto it = std::begin(p_list); it != std::end(p_list); ++it) {
            m_list[i++] = *it;
        }
    };
    friend std::ostream &::operator<<(std::ostream & oStream, Base const &rhs);
    friend std::ostream &::operator<<(std::ostream & oStream, Base &&rhs);

   int size() { return m_list.size(); }
private:
    std::vector<std::string> m_list;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {};
    Derived(Derived &&rhs) : Base(std::move(rhs)) {
        std::cout << "DerivedMove_Construktor(" << Base::size() << ',' << rhs.m_numbers.size() << ')' << std::endl;
        m_numbers = std::move(rhs.m_numbers);
    }
    Derived(std::initializer_list<std::string> &&p_list, std::initializer_list<double> &&p_numbers) 
    : Base(std::move(p_list))
    {
        int i=0;
        std::cout << "Derived-List_Construktor(" << Base::size() << ',' << p_numbers.size() << ')' << std::endl;
        m_numbers.resize(p_numbers.size());
        for(auto it = std::begin(p_numbers); it != std::end(p_numbers); ++it) {
            m_numbers[i++] = *it;
        }
    };
    friend std::ostream &::operator<<(std::ostream & oStream, Derived const &rhs);

private:
    std::vector<double> m_numbers;
};


std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream & oStream, Base const &rhs) 
{
    oStream << "{ "; 
    for(auto it = std::begin(rhs.m_list); it != std::end(rhs.m_list); ++it) 
    {
        oStream << '"' << *it << "\", ";
    }
    oStream << '}'; 
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream & oStream, Base &&rhs) 
{
    oStream << "{m: "; 
    for(auto it = std::begin(rhs.m_list); it != std::end(rhs.m_list); ++it) 
    {
        oStream << '"' << *it << "\", ";
    }
    oStream << '}'; 
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream & oStream, Derived const &rhs) 
{
    oStream << '{'; 
    for(auto it = std::begin(rhs.m_numbers); it != std::end(rhs.m_numbers); ++it) 
    {
        oStream <<  *it << ", ";
    }
    oStream << (Base const &)rhs << '}'; 
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;

    std::cout << Base({ "tafel", "kreide", "Schwamm" }) << std::endl;

    Base base{ "tafel", "kreide", "Schwamm" };
    std::cout << base << std::endl;

    Derived derived({ "tafel", "kreide", "Schwamm" }, { 0.2342, 8.639 });
    std::cout << derived << std::endl;
    Derived derivedCopy(std::move(derived));
    std::cout << "derived is empty now:   " << derived << std::endl;
    std::cout << "derivedCopy holds data: " << derivedCopy << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Small correction: you can call `std::move` all you want. It is only when the resulting rvalue reference is consumed somehow that the moved-from value becomes invalid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move constructor for derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668952/move-constructor-for-derived-class)

Comment: Yeah, that *hidden* knowledge makes variant one working. However it looks cruel to my. moving `rhs` out and accessing `rhs.m_dataDerived` in the next line.

Comment: Thanksto  JBL, but this post does not deal with data-encapsulation and private members.
I would like to get advice which variant is the better one or even better some third way eventually as I pointed out in "What is missing is..."

Comment: @Xantopp No indeed, but it shows you that the first variant that you kinda want in order to maintain encapsulation and thought was "breaking" the rule of not using something that has been moved from after the move, is actually is fine in that context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Derived::Derived(Derived &&rhs)
: Base(std::move(rhs))
, m_dataDerived(std::move(rhs.m_dataDerived))
{}
```

This code is correct and idiomatic. If you want, you can write it in a way that clarifies how only the `Base` part is moved:

```
Derived::Derived(Derived &&rhs)
: Base(std::move(static_cast<Base&&>(rhs)))
, m_dataDerived(std::move(rhs.m_dataDerived))
{}
```

We only move the `Base` subobject of the `Derived`. Indeed, the `Base` subobject of `rhs` is in a valid but (by convention) undefined state after calling the `Base` move constructor with it, so we better not assume anything about it. But we clearly didn't touch `m_dataDerived`, so moving from it afterwards is fine.

I would advise against writing code like the above (with extra `static_cast`) though. For starters, the `std::move` actually becomes pointless (but leaving it out makes the code even less readable). In the context of a move constructor, the intention and effect of move-constructing the base from `std::move(rhs)` directly should be perfectly clear and idiomatic.

Your first rule (*"I've learned, that `std::move` does nothing, but after `std::move(someDObject)` the Object `someDObject` may be canibalized and you should not access `someDObject`"*) is also inaccurate:

1. The object *may* be cannibalized, but only by operations that can cannibalize. So accessing an object after calling `std::move` is not *necessarily* bad (but presumably someone put the `std::move` there for a reason, and you won't go wrong by assuming cannibalization).
2. You *can* access a moved-from object. But you shouldn't do anything with it that makes any assumption about its state (beyond it being valid, which is required for eventual destruction). In standard library terms, you can only use operations on/of the object that have no preconditions. So you can `reset` a `std::unique_ptr` that was moved from, you can call `size()` on a moved-from `std::vector` and so on.

That's of course not terribly relevant for move construction, but it pays to understand what exactly is happening.